# How can I position my text and background to my needs using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the first part of my page the background is called `intro-section`. I was wondering how I could move my text which is above the animated theme which is coloured in white to be in front of the black red dotted animated theme in the middle centre?

In addition, would it be possible if you could make the red dotted animation background to fill the background of the "intro-section" only.

I have spent hours on this, sorry if it's a simple fix it's just i'm new to web development.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/liamdocherty1/pen/awwBQX)

Comment: I noticed in your codepen that you have redundant body tag in line 11 of your html code. I recommend that you clean some of the code so we can help you better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is to add `position: absolute` to `#intro .col-lg-12.text-center`:

```
#intro .col-lg-12.text-center {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I've created an updated CodePen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRRLEM)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem; happy to help! :)